# How do I serialize an entire ActiveRecord Tree in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization, tree

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  belongs_to :parent_node, :class_name => "Node", :foreign_key => :parent_id
  has_many :child_nodes, :class_name => "Node", :foreign_key => :parent_id
end
```

For the root node, parent_id will be nill.
Say I have the id of the root node, and wish to print the entire tree to the output stream in json format.

How do I go about doing that?

Assume the tree does not contain any loops.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944005/how-to-generate-json-tree-from-ancestry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set). The [wiki](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/wiki/Awesome-nested-set-cheat-sheet) is well documented but can be hard to find if you don't know it's there.

In your case, you'll want to do something like:

```
Node.root.self_and_descendants
```

Comment: I was hoping what I wanted was in rails base, but this looks like it solves the problem, thanks :)